# Laravel validation rule to restrict umlauts in email addresses (international domain names)

Tags: php, regex, laravel, idn

I need to restrict the usage of German umlauts (äÄöÖüÜ) in email addresses.

So I quickly created a custom validation rule in my `AppServiceProvider`:

```
Validator::extend('without_umlauts', function ($attribute, $value) {
    return preg_match('/^[^äÄöÖüÜ]*$/u', $value);
});
```

The regex (see [visualization](https://embed.ihateregex.io/make/JTVFJTVCJTVFJUMzJUE0JUMzJTg0JUMzJUI2JUMzJTk2JUMzJUJDJUMzJTlDJTVEKiUyNA)) seems to work pretty much as expected and detects the given umlauts in basic strings.

The validation rule above works with input fields `type="text"` and the following input values:

```
täst@example.com
jane-doe@täst.com
```

However, the rule does not work in Google Chrome as soon as I use `type="email"`.
I assume the reason for this is that behind the scenes <s>Laravel</s> Google Chrome casts the domain part of the email address to IDNA ASCII:

```
jane-doe@xn--tst-qla.com
```

I already tried to use [`idn_to_utf8()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.idn-to-utf8.php) on the `$value` but it didn't work.

How can I restrict the usage of umlauts (special characters) in the domain name of the email address?
Umlauts should not be allowed in the whole email address string.

Update: It works perfectly well in Firefox. It seems to be a browser-related issue (instead of Regex/Laravel).

Comment: Read [this](https://justmarkup.com/articles/2015-02-13-input-type-email-better-dont-use-it/). Why not use `input=text` since you do email validation on it anyway?

Comment: Laravel is not modifying your input depending on which type you are using in your form, Laravel does and can not know the input type that was used in the form, it just accepts the data, most likely your browser and their implementation of `type="email"` are modifying the value being sent.

Comment: @i-- Thank you for your input. I'm currently using `type="text"` as a workaround. I always thought `type="email"` would help the user (built-in form validation, a different keyboard on mobile) but I'll consider moving away from this input type.

Comment: @Remul Thank you for your feedback as well. You are right. It seems to be an issue in Google Chrome. It works in Firefox.